# In the song »Sah ein Knab' ein Röslein stehn«

Tags: article, lyrics, objects

In the famous song "Sah ein Knab' ein Röslein stehn", in the 3rd verse,

> Und der wilde Knabe brach
>   **'s** Röslein auf der Heiden;
>   Röslein wehrte sich und stach,
>   Half ihm doch kein Weh und Ach,

What's the `'s`  in the second line? Is it 'Es' referring to the Röslein? Or is it the article 'Das' ? I know the author (Goethe) put 'brach' at the end to rhyme it with 'stach'. By the way, what a beatiful lyric and song!

Comment: Lines are not so much blurred in this poem.

Comment: The *es* as personal pronoun is impossible here, since the substantive is directly following and not in a different (partial) sentence - no need to  refer to something, which is already there. In general (e. g. *'s ist spät*) *'s* may stand for *es*, however.

Comment: @guidot, ok I suspected 'es' as the objective workd for brach.

Comment: "what a beatiful lyric" - at least the underlying meaning as I learned it in school is not exactly "beautiful".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I understand it's a story between a boy(der Knabe) and a girl(das Roslein). I also have an impression the boy might had done something bad the girl didn't want.  But it's all metaphore and this poem doesn't say explicitly what it is. I think this peom is beautilful by itself without the metaphore. And sometimes, things are best left unsaid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `'s` stands for the article "das". So the long form would be

> Und der wilde Knabe brach
>   das Röslein auf der Heiden;

Answer (score 4):

The *'s* in the second line indeed means *das*.

In german, we use the apostrophe to signify that letters were omitted.